# What does $() in jquery mean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I know $() is a selector , but I can't figure out what it selects, since there's nothing inside parenthesis. Is this a good practice or bad?

Example where I see it used...making a call to a data service.

```
$().dataService({
  url: getURL('application', data),
  params: params,
  success: getResponse,
  error: errorResponse
})
```

Comment: Do you have an example of where this was used? I can't come up with a reason why you would use an empty jQuery selector.

Comment: @KJPrice Well, there is some reasons... I often use it.

Comment: please see my edit in my post. i included example

Comment: `$()` is not a selector. It's a function call. The string typically passed to `$` represents a selector.

Comment: `dataService` is a function set in the prototype object of jQuery. from what it look like, it doesn't need a reference to a jQuery object, so `$().dataService` works. It a kinda bad programming IMO. Instead of declaring `dataService` like that : `$.fn.dataService`, i would do it like that : `$.dataService` **then** use it that way : `$.dataService()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JQuery 1.4 Release Notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14):

> In jQuery 1.3, jQuery() returned a jQuery set containing just the document. in jQuery 1.4, it returns an empty jQuery set. This can be useful for creating an empty set and adding elements to it dynamically.

So to answer your question, it selects nothing, returning an empty set. This is perfectly acceptable to use, and not considered bad practice.